# Problem with Security Information Message Pop Up Box

Tags: https

I am having great issues trying to debug a page on a web application used internally on an intranet. When entering the page the "Security Information" Pop Up Box appears. The whole application is running under https.

To try and debug the issue, I have used Fiddler, and looked at the urls for every component, javascript, css, images, and user control components. Everything I have seen from Fiddler shows that the urls start with required https!

So, I am completely confused why this message should be shown - it appears everything the page is posted back.

Does anyone have any idea why this should be happening and/or have another tool that could help me?

Thanks

Comment: I have the answer, but since I know you won't accept I won't bother to provide it.

Comment: Have you both seen that I have accepted answers?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that what you are seeing is the result of a self-signed certificate.  If a certificate you're using isn't trusted by a known certificate authority (Verisign or a similar company) your web browser can't verify that it comes from a trusted source.

Also, look at what the error is saying, because it usually tells you which part of the security verification failed.